# How to use CameraX in foreground service? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, background-service, android-camerax, foreground-service

I need to use the Camera frames even the app is in background. After I have searched how to do it I encountered to foreground service. However, when the app is in background, the streaming from the PreviewView stops, so I cannot use the advantage of using foreground service.

| Camera | State |
| --- | --- |
| `Camera@50536c5[id=1]` | CLOSED |
| `Camera@c3b62c2[id=0]` | UNKNOWN |
| `Camera@a1a5527[id=2]` | UNKNOWN |

Whenever I touch the home button, the warning above comes to Log-cat and stop delivering frames to ImageAnalysis. I cannot process the frames.

Is there a way to keep the streaming of frames awake, even the app is on background?

ps : manifest has been edited as `android:foregroundServiceType="camera"`

Comment: I saw some other posts by you, did you figure this out?

Im trying to get recording in the background and having issues

Comment: It's been long since I didn't work for that, but you do not use the previewView to receive the data as far as I remember..

Comment: How do you show the video without a preview view?